# How to implement htmleditor in extjs project using modern toolkit and 6.5.2 version

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I'm developing an extjs project using 6.5.2 version and modern tookit, i need to use a html editor to improve a functionallity that my project need, i was reading about htmleditor component but only classic toolkit contain it.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243418

So i'm looking for a library that let me use a similar component and i found https://www.tiny.cloud/ so i was trying to implement this but it didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

The last code represent the basic implementation to use tiny, i added the script resources en app.json and a container with a html attribute representing the textarea needed but it didn't show the component.

```
var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  bodyPadding: 5,  // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
  width: 300,
  title: 'Filters',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    html: '<textarea>Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny! 
           </textarea>'
  }],
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Does anyone know how to implement tiny library in an extjs project or a similar HTML editor component that i can use in the modern toolkit?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script libraries for html editor, something like https://quilljs.com/. You bring in external java script components from "render" event of a component.